# Puppeteer- How to use waitForSelector?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to check if an aria-invalid is false inside a for-loop and consle log the letter that work. but it logs every letter regardless of if its true or false.

i am wondering if i'm using the waitforselector properly?

```
    letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
      Name = "Name";
      for (var i = 36; i--;) {         
      for (var j = 36; j--;)
      { 
        await page.type('input[name="Username"]', Name + letters[i]+letters[j], 
        await page.waitFor(50),
        await page.click('[name="firstName"]'),
        await page.waitFor(500),
        page.waitForSelector('[aria-invalid="false"]').then(() =>console.log(letters[i]+letters[j])),
        await page.click('[name="Username"]'), 
        await page.waitFor(500),
        await page.keyboard.press('Backspace'), // Deletes the Name+ij
        await page.keyboard.press('Backspace'),
        await page.keyboard.press('Backspace'),
        await page.keyboard.press('Backspace'),
        await page.keyboard.press('Backspace'),
        await page.keyboard.press('Backspace'),
        await 

page.waitFor(100),
     )}
```

[Here is the where aria-invaild is in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvBfO.png)

Comment: Could you please show the block of that code, especially where the `letter`, `i`, and `j` initialized? so we may identify your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Given just the code here taken out of context, there's nothing wrong per se. Please link to the live website or show the HTML [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), with any relevant JS needed to reproduce the unwanted behavior. See [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: It seems you need `await` before: `await page.waitForSelector().then()`

Comment: if i use  `await page.waitForSelector().then()` it will get stuck on the  line on the for-loop

Comment: if you want to check it and not wait for it use page.$